# Run a drush command via module

Tags: drush

Is there a way to run a Drush command using a module? I tried `exec("drush ...");` but I have found out it is not recommended. Is there any other command I could use?

Comment: What command do you want to run and why?

Comment: It's a command that activates/deactivates a table when the stocks are 0.

Comment: it also schedules a clear cache after 3 minutes or so.

Comment: You may use a cron instead

Comment: Any tips how I can use cron? I'm not that used to it yet. How can I assign it to a cron job?

Comment: That's a totally different question, but there's lot information about that subject that you can browse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use [`drush_invoke_process()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!drush!includes!command.inc/function/drush_invoke/7) rather than `exec()`.

```
$values = drush_invoke_process("@site", "cc", array("all"), array("verbose"));
```

Comment: drush_sitealias_get_record and drush_invoke_process are undefined. Do i need to include any class or file in my custom drupal 8 module?

Answer (score 0):

drush_invoke_process() can be used in a drush context. Since cron is executed via drush you can used it inside a cron.